# parse_ini_file doesn't parse custom env variables

Tags: php, environment-variables

The variables `$_ENV['MYSQL_USERNAME']` and `$_ENV['MYSQL_PASSWORD']` are set via the dotenv plugin of vlucas (they are read from a .env file and stored as env variables).

When I try to parse this piece of text in a .ini file via the `parse_ini_file` function:

```
db.username = ${MYSQL_USERNAME}
db.password = ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

It returns:

```
array(db.username => '', db.password => '');
```

When I set these 2 MYSQL variables inside my vhosts file (SetEnv MYSQL_USERNAME bla) the `parse_ini_file` does replace the username var with "bla".

I don't get why the .env method doesn't work.

EDIT: In linux this seems to work fine. Only on Windows `parse_ini_file` returns an array with empty values.

Comment: Where did you find in the documentation of [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) that it cares about the environment variables?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#99943

Comment: That is not documentation. It is a user comment and it clearly says *"Undocumented feature"*. You cannot rely on implementation details. They can change or vanish on the next release without notice. But you can rely on a documented feature: `parse_ini_file()` replaces the constants.

Comment: replaces the constants? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: [Example #2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#refsect1-function.parse-ini-file-examples) says *"[Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) may also be parsed in the ini file so if you define a constant as an ini value before running `parse_ini_file()`, it will be integrated into the results."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code in double quotes and avoid spaces arround equal `=`

```
db.username="${MYSQL_USERNAME}"
db.password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
```

That can solve your problem.

### UPDATE

You can genetare `.ini` file each time you want to save data into it using simple `fopen()` and `fwrite()` function.

```
// destroy old INI file
if(file_exists('example.ini'))
    unlink('example.ini');
// generate new INI file
$example = fopen("example.ini", "w");
$str="
; User data
db.username=\"${MYSQL_USERNAME}\"
db.password=\"${MYSQL_PASSWORD}\"
";
fwrite($example, $str);
fclose($example);
```

Comment: This does not work: gives the same output with empty values.

Comment: What is `MYSQL_PASSWORD` and `MYSQL_USERNAME`? Is instances or variables or some shortcodes? How you define it and wat you expect instand of it?

Comment: The variables are read via the dotenv plugin from a .env file.

The contents of this file are:
MYSQL_USERNAME = root
MYSQL_PASSWORD = ""

Comment: Holdon, you basically first prepare content into string and save into .ini file right? Can yu update your question with real example of code? I think I have solution but need to be 100% shure you do right thing.

Comment: The question already contains real code: I read a .env file via the dotenv plugin. After that I try to replace the variables inside my .ini file with the values read from the .ini file (which are in $_ENV/$_SERVER now).

Comment: from my experience it will be better to generate ini file over and over via fopen. Do all settings you need inside PHP code and easly replace old file with new data. Look my updated answer.